# Can I make an iPhone ring on cue without making an actual call?

Tags: iphone

The theater company I work with is doing a show this fall in which a key plot point is an iPhone ringing while it's in someone's purse. They really want to make an iPhone ring and not just use a sound cue. But cell reception inside the theater is spotty at best. Is there some way to get an iPhone to ring without making a call to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect Your iPhone to WiFi (so that it has access to the internet) and ring via FaceTime.

To change FaceTime ringtone go to **Preferences** -> **Notifications** -> **FaceTime**.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to simulate the effect of an iPhone ringing:

1. Set a timer in the Clock app with the alert sound set to Marimba (the default iOS ringtone). However, this would require knowing exactly how long to wait before the sound plays.
2. Load an MP3 file of the default Marimba ringtone into the Music app and play it via a Bluetooth controller. Slightly more complex than the first option but allows more flexibility in the act.

Unless there is something theatrically different between these options and an actual phone call to the iPhone, these are the only options I can think of without cell reception or wifi.